# SQL How to count user increase day after day

Tags: sql, count

I have a database with user logins records. 
Simplify it to this one:
| login_date | user_id |

I would like to measure unique users increase. So the result will be a growing number of unique users day by day.
In other words. It has to count a number of unique users day by day and compare whether there is a unique user_id in relation to the set from a previous day. If yes it has to add it to the set, if not, it has to rewrite a number of users from the previous day. So it will constantly add a unique user_id and count it.

Does anybody faced similar problem? I don't know how to start.

Comment: that has something to do with ur database design. does ur table store the last login or creation time? if it does, its straight forward.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Your statement *I have a database* does not provide enough information... Please edit your question and tag with RDBMS (product and version). With SQL Server 2012+ this might be something to do with `SUM() OVER()`

Comment: I'm using Presto.